# Remove Price from a file using Sed

Tags: shell

Can you please help me to write a sed command to remove the price from a file?

Input:

```
1 Printer
2 Network Swtich
1 82lb A4 Paper Rim
$20
```

Output:

```
1 Printer
2 Network Swtich
1 82lb A4 Paper Rim
```

$20 eliminated from the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in /tmp/foo:

```
sed '/^\$/d' /tmp/foo
```

Use the pattern match to find lines that start with a dollar sign, then delete those lines from the pattern space and start the next cycle.